# How can I symlink a folder and change its name?

Tags: symlink

I'm working in a monorepo and I want the example for my packages to be separated from the packages in a structure as follows:

```
my_packages_collection/
  examples/
    foo/
     ...
  packages/
    foo/
      example
      ...
```

If I cd in `my_packages_collection` and run `ln -s examples/foo packages/foo/example`
I get in `packages/foo` a file named `example` and not a folder.

If I run `cd packages/foo/example` I get: `cd: no such file or directory: packages/foo/example` and `vscode` shows instead:

```
Unable to read file '[...]/foo/example' (Unknown (FileSystemError): An unknown error occurred. Please consult the log for more details.)
```

`ls -l` works as intended.

"pushed" it for science and on github and shows a "linked folder" icon that contains a file with text `"examples/foo"` (LOL)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to `chdir` into `packages/foo` and make the symbolic link from there:

```
$ mkdir my_packages_collection && cd my_packages_collection
$ mkdir -p examples/foo packages/foo
$ touch examples/foo/bar
$ cd packages/foo && ln -s ../../examples/foo example
$ ls example
bar
```

Another way is to make the link without the `chdir`. This will be more difficult to tab complete on in the shell.

```
$ cd -
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf my_packages_collection
$ mkdir my_packages_collection && cd my_packages_collection
$ mkdir -p examples/foo packages/foo
$ touch examples/foo/bar
$ ln -s ../../examples/foo packages/foo/example
$ ls packages/foo/example
bar
```

The result of either of these methods is a symbolic link file that contains the string `../../examples/foo` in it.

```
$ readlink packages/foo/example
../../examples/foo
```